# quotation marks changes from simply to twice in c#

Tags: xml

I have an XML-Dokument which contains simply a quotation mark `'`but when i open this document and remove something and save it later every simply quotation mark `'` is changed to a double quotation mark `"`.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: what program are you opening the document with? Notepad?

Comment: How are you opening, removing something, and saving it?

Comment: I'm using C#. This is the code that im using for opening, searching, removing and saving.

private void DeleteNode(String ArtID)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
            foreach (var profileElement in (from profileElement in doc.Descendants("bA")
                                            where profileElement.Attribute("bD").Value == arD
                                            select profileElement).ToList())
            {
                profileElement.Remove();
            }

            doc.Save(newpath);
        }

Comment: I'd change your question to include your code to be more complete.